# Pandas - Convert a column of 1D arrays to a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe with a single column where each row is a 1D array.

```
     my_col
0    [1,2,3,4]
1    [5,6,7,9]
2    [8,5,4,3]
3    [3,6,8,0]
4    [2,4,6,8]
```

Where [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,9], etc. are all 1D arrays of shape (4,). I want to convert this column into an array of 1D arrays. I.e., an array of shape(5,4).

But, if I try `np.array(df['my_col'].values)`, the shape I get is (5,). But, how do I get (5,4)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert values to lists and then to `np.array`:

```
np.array(df['my_col'].tolist())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

```py
np.stack(df["my_col"].values)
```